# Moment with typescript+angular2

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs

i using the moment js library and everything okay except one thing.

Using initialization like this don't look good. I don't want import everything from 'moment'

```
import * as moment  from 'moment/moment';
```

One place where i use moment it:

```
        var differenceBeteweenDates = moment(toDate, this.dateFormat)
            .diff(moment(fromDate, this.dateFormat),
            "days");
```

i need Import only necessary modules/functions. How i can do it?

```
 ps: import { Moment }  from 'moment/moment'; - don't contain all things what i need
```

Comment: That's correct way: `import * as moment from 'moment';`

Comment: Maybe correct, but i need another)

Comment: Typescript imports don't import specific function. When you compite this to javascript, the code is transpiled to require('moment'). There is nothing you can do

Comment: I think what you want (and me too!) is something like the way you can choose to only import one operator, e.g. Observable or toPromise, with rxjs rather than the whole package.  Don't think moment.js is modularize like this (yet....)

Answer (score 0):

`import { Moment, fn, utc as moment } from 'moment/moment';` and use `moment.` or `moment()` what you need